# SLQAlchemy, Flask: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'create_all'

Tags: virtualenv, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having this issue when creating the tables using SQLAlquemy in Flask, in a virtualenv.

I do:

```
>>> from mod_db import modelx
>>> modelx.create_all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'create_all'
```

modelx is:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://gaz:123@localhost:5432/test'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

db classes...
```

What can it be?

Thanks!

Comment: If there’s no `def create_all():` in modelx, that’d be it. Did you mean `modelx.db.create_all`?

Comment: Bingo. Reply that please and i'll make it the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re trying to use the `create_all` on `db`, that’d be it.

```
modelx.db.create_all()
```